# Failure creating clojure project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, clojure, enclojure

I decided to take a look at Clojure and thought the best and easiest method for me would be to use Netbeans with the Enclojure plugin as I didn't want to have to learn Emacs at the same time.  I installed Netbeans 6.9.1 together with the latest JDK using the bundled install (on Windows 7).  All went smoothly. I then followed the instructions at http://www.enclojure.org/gettingstarted for installing the enclojure plugin.

When creating a new Clojure application I get the following and see no project files :

java.io.IOException: Could not connect to URL nbresloc:/org/enclojure/ide/templates/project/ClojureProjectTemplate-1.1-distribution.zip. No such resource was found.

- Maven is working using mvn --version
- I have installed on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 (same result).
- I have looked on the Enclojure forum and there is a recent open thread for this issue, but it is not solved by anybody presently.
- I have Java SE enabled in Netbeans
- I have tried enabling the different platform versions of Clojure, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, etc..
- The REPL seems to be working happily in Netbeans : (printf "hello") hellonill
- I did try ClojureBox on Windows 7, but again that's Emacs, but emacs failed to start the server and hung there and became totally unresponsive.
- I come from a .Net background (not Java) so my knowledge of the Java environment is somewhat lacking.  My reason for looking at Clojure and not Java.
- I am new to Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in a working Maven pom, here is one I've used with Enclojure successfully:

- http://puredanger.com/techfiles/100624/pom.xml

There are some project settings you'll need to change and a few dependencies to remove but it might be a good start.  In general, I usually create the pom first and then just import the project into NetBeans rather than using the NetBeans options to create projects.

By the way, the REPL work in Enclojure has been split and is coming soon to the Eclipse plugin Counterclockwise.

Comment: what do you mean by "the REPL work" ? and how do you know that ? :P

Comment: I mean "the code that implements the REPL in NetBeans".  There has been extensive talk about it in the Enclojure and Counterclockwise mailing lists lately.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have installed IntelliJ for now and will start with that.  Once I get more familiar with clojure in general then I may start to experiment with other IDEs, but IntelliJ support for clojure seemed easy enough to set up in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a small [post](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/02/clojure-for-netbeans-7/) on it on my [blog](http://jatinpuri.com).
Anyways here is the procedure:
On searching realized that this is a common problem for installing it on > Netbeans 7.*. But with some manual tweeks managed to install it. Here are the instructions to install on Netbeans 7.* plus:

1. Install Netbeans 7. You need only the Java SE version.
2. First Run of Netbeans after installation. Activate feature Java SE
       Activate features is on the Start page or from Tools,->Plugins>Installed, click ‘Activate next to the Java SE support
3. Install Maven:  It is HIGHLY recommended that you install maven: http://maven.apache.org/download.html
4. Go to the Netbeans->Preferences, click on the Miscellaneous tab and make sure the External Maven Home path is pointed to your maven install
5. Download the EnClojure 1.5 version from [here](http://enclojure.org/file/detail/org-enclojure-plugin-1.5.0.nbm/223543600). If you want  to manually build, you can do that by following the instructions from [here](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/02/clojure-for-netbeans-7/www.enclojure.org/For+Developers).
6. After downloading the file, In Netbeans: Goto:- Tools ->Plugins->Downloaded->Add Plugins->Downloaded
7. Then browse to the downloaded file. Later install by clicking at the “install : button.
   Restart and you are on the go.

Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619346/a-hello-world-using-netbeans-7-0-enclojure-1-5) to build and run hello world project.Basically building the EnClojure 1.5 manually is the tough job. I hope above was useful.