# A "hello world" using Netbeans 7.0 Enclojure 1.5

Tags: netbeans, clojure

I just started learning Clojure. I would like to use Netbeans but I have no idea how to setup a simple app the spits out anything. I followed the setup for the Enclojure plugin and everything seems good. Can anybody give a short tutorial or a hint to one on the setup.

Comment: There are some problems in installing the plugin for Netbeans 7.* plus as you will have to manually build it. You can find [instructions](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/02/clojure-for-netbeans-7/) to install the plugin from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prerequisites:

```
Netbeans 7
EnClojure Plugin
Maven set up correctly
    Maven installed
    Maven Proxy setup if behind a proxy
    Netbeans: Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Maven
```

Project Setup:

```
Menu File > New Project > Clojure > Clojure 1.2 Maven Project
Projectname= HelloWorld
Default Namespace= com.jfcorbet.helloword
```

Browse Project:

```
Projects Window > Source Packages > com.jfcorbet > helloworld.clj
```

You'll see:

```
(ns com.jfcorbet.helloworld
    ;(:import )
    ;(:require )
)
```

Add:

```
(defn hello
"Prints Hello and name parameter"
     [name]
     (println (str "Hello " name)))

(hello "Jean-François")
```

and save.

Now Rightclick your project and choose "Build with Dependencies", this should make Maven download the clojure and contrib libraries, and take care of the dependencies.

then

```
Rightclick your project and choose "Start Project REPL"
    Project window > helloworld.clj > RMB > choose "Load Sources in Repl"
    or select source text and RMB > "Evaluate Expr in REPL"
```

Comment: For the more clueless among us (like me), when you say "Right click the helloworld.clj and choose "Load Sources in Repl", you mean right click the file name in the Projects tree, not the editor.